# Android - Google maps markers moving around

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

For some reason I'm noticing that the markers that I download the icon for don't stick in their lon/lat when I zoom in and out. However, if I use assets that are in the project it doesn't happen. Does anyone know why?

I'm loading the assets using:

```
Picasso.with(mActivity).load(strUrl).into(currentMarker.getCurrentMarker());
```

--EDIT --

```
public class CustomMarker implements Target {

    Marker mMarker;
    private boolean doneLoad;

    public CustomMarker(Marker marker) {

        mMarker = marker;
        doneLoad = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return mMarker.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof CustomMarker) {
            Marker marker = ((CustomMarker) o).mMarker;
            return mMarker.equals(marker);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)  throws IllegalArgumentException {

        if (doneLoad == false) {
            try {
                mMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
                doneLoad = true;
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }


    public Marker getmMarker() {
        return mMarker;
    }

    public boolean isDoneLoad() {
        return doneLoad;
    }

    public void setDoneLoad(boolean doneLoad) {
        this.doneLoad = doneLoad;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the `Target` implementation that you are using?

Comment: I would say that the problem is an incorrect anchor of the icon. Could you add `mMarker.setAnchor(0.5f,1f);` after `setIcon` on your `CustomMarker.onBitmapLoaded`?

Comment: @antonio thanks! it worked!

Comment: Glad to help! I'm posting it as an answer so it can help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the icon is incorrectly anchored.

Add this after `setIcon` on your `CustomMarker.onBitmapLoaded`:

```
mMarker.setAnchor(0.5f,1f);
```